# Shared folder stops being shared after reboot

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, google-drive

I work at a small office where we use GSuite for our office and network needs (i.e., instead of a typical shared drive, we use Google Drive mounted as a network share. From the end user perspective, it's the same as standard Windows networking, but I'm guessing Windows doesn't see it that way.

We have two printers that are capable of scanning. One of them is configured to scan to Google Drive. So far, so good. The other one doesn't have such capability, so it's configured to scan to a shared folder on my Windows 10 machine, which is always on. This shared folder actually lives on Google Drive. Google drive on my machine is mapped to `G:` and the shared folder is at `G:\some path\shared folder`.

This works fine until I reboot my machine. After rebooting, `G:\some path\shared folder` is no longer shared.

Is there a way to either:

1. Stop Windows from dropping the share; or
2. Write a script that runs at boot or on login which checks for the share and creates it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To recreate the share after a reboot, you may use the Task Scheduler to run a script
that creates it after the boot.

The command to use in the script is
[net share](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh750728(v=ws.11)).
It will look something like:

```
net share sharename="G:\some path\shared folder"
```

The tricky part here will be ensuring that `G:` is already available when the script
is run.

Comment: Don't forget to specify permissions - by default it creates a share accessible to everyone, probably not what you want.